# I have to remove static+dynamic text from string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have to remove `pic.twitter.com/yzvksTiMjH` from my news titles.

It appears anywhere in the title.

`pic.twitter.com/` is static but the text after slash (`/`) is not static and it always have 10 alphabets.

Need Help ...

Thanks

Comment: Tried `preg_replace` : `/\bpic.twitter.com\/\w{10}\b/`?

Comment: What is that `\b` meant to do in that regex?

Comment: This is one of the most simple regular expressions to write. What problem are you having with it? Have you bothered to read a tutorial on regular expressions? You're not going to learn it by having other people write it for you.

Comment: @Barmar ... I want to learn it ... Kindly send me a good tutorial ... thanks

Comment: www.regular-expression.info

Comment: @barmer ... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
/\bpic.twitter.com\/\w{10}\b/
```

This regex: 
- `\b` : boundary
- `pic.twitter.com` : literals
- `\w{10}` : any word with length of 10

Comment: @abasit83 Glad that it helped!